# Cannot call method in other class

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the page object file: login.py

```
from pages.base import BasePage
from config import secrets
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class LoginPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self):
        self.webdriver = BasePage.webdriver
        port = raw_input("Enter port number: ")
        self.url = "http://localhost:" + port

    @property
    def retrieve_username_field(self):
        self.webdriver.find_element_by_name("username")

    @property
    def retrieve_password_field(self):
        self.webdriver.find_element_by_name("password")

    def login(self, username=None, password=None):
        username = username or secrets.username
        password = password or secrets.password
        self.retrieve_username_field.send_keys(username)
        self.retrieve_password_field.send_keys(password)
        self.retrieve_password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Here is the base page file: base.py

```
from selenium import webdriver

class BasePage(object):
    webdriver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def go(self):
        self.webdriver.get(self.url)
```

Here is the test file: test_login.py

```
import unittest

from pages.login import LoginPage

login_page = LoginPage()

def setUpModule():
    login_page.go()

def tearUpModule():
    login_page.logout()


class TestLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_login_succeeds_with_valid_credentials(self):
        login_page.login()
        xpath = "//th[text() = 'Spool Name']"
        self.assertIsNotNone(login_page.webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is that I get this error: http://puu.sh/9JgRd/e61f5acec3.png and I'm not sure why I cannot call login method. I have reference to LoginPage object but failure happens exactly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that you can't call `login()`, but that `self.retrieve_username_field` returns `None` and thus does not have a `send_keys` method. 
That's exactly what the error you get is telling you.

Comment: Okay, but what is wrong with the code then? I inserted print statements and webdriver.current_url returns correct url. print self.webdriver returns an object not None. And the method is correct because it would throw non-existant method error. Also, the name of the input field is correct. I added implicit wait but it does not work, it returns this error immediately even though the implicit wait is before the property's call.

Comment: Omg...forgot a return :D